# Add colon to 24 hour time in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, datetime-format, valueconverter

I have a date in the format **MM/DD/YYYY** and time in the format **HHMM** (24 hour time w/o the colon).  Both of these strings are in an array.  I would like to store this as one string - maybe something like **"MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM"** - and then be able to convert it to a written date like **"January 1, 2014 16:15"** when I am showing it to the user.  How can I do this?

This is the code that I have:

```
String date = "05/27/2014 23:01";
Date df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm").parse(date);
System.out.println(df);
```

However this is what I get: "Sun Dec 29 23:01:00 EST 2013"

The output I am looking for is: "December 29, 2013 23:01"

Comment: What you have tried so far? show us some cod.e

Comment: *"Thanks,
   Josh"*   Noise.  Leave it out in future.  If your name is that important to you, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3015565/user3015565).

Comment: I haven't tried anything thus far.  I have thought about using a unix timestamp but I'm not quite sure what would be most efficient.

Comment: What kind of research have you completed **before** posting your question here? Please share your preliminary results with us.

Comment: "I haven't tried anything thus far". It is better to try something first, which may give you some clues to make your life easier.

Comment: Check out one of the [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559177/how-to-convert-yyydd-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-using-java) that come up on the right

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleDateFormat` is the way to go; to parse your Strings in the required meaningful date and time formats and finally print your date as a required String.

You specify the 2 formats as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
```

Considering a simple hardcoded array of date and time (not the best way to show but your question calls it an array):

```
String[] array = { "12/31/2013", "1230" };
```

You would have to set these parsed dates in a Calendar instance:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, time.getHours());
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time.getMinutes());
```

Finally format your date using the same `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm");
```

**Here is the complete working code:**

```
public class DateExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");

        String[] array = { "12/31/2013", "1230" };

        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(array[0]);
            Date time = timeFormat.parse(array[1]);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, time.getHours());
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time.getMinutes());

            SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm");
            String datePrint = newFormat.format(cal.getTime());

            System.out.println(datePrint);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**The output:**

> December 31, 2013 at 12:30

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the existing answers has mentioned the root cause of the problem which is as follows:

- You have used `D` (which specifies *Day in year*) instead of `d` (*Day in month*).
- You have used `Y` (which specifies *Week year*) instead of `y` (*Year*).

Learn more about it at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page. Now that you have understood the root cause of the problem, let's focus on the solution using the best standard API of the time.

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

I would solve it in the following steps:

1. Parse the date string into `LocalDate`.
2. Parse the time string into `LocalTime`.
3. Combine the objects of `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` to obtain an object of `LocalDateTime`.
4. Format the object of `LocalDateTime` into the desired pattern.

**Demo using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Parse the date string into `LocalDate`.
        DateTimeFormatter dateParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("01/01/2014", dateParser);

        // 2. Parse the time string into `LocalTime`.
        DateTimeFormatter timeParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("1615", timeParser);

        // 3. Combine date and time to obtain an object of `LocalDateTime`.
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.atTime(time);

        // 4. Format the object of `LocalDateTime` into the desired pattern.
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, uuuu HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = dtfOutput.format(ldt);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
January 1, 2014 16:15
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.text.DateFormat class to convert date to string(format method), and string to date(parse method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` both to parse Strings into dates and to format Dates back into Strings.  Here's your example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");

    String dateString = "05/27/2014 23:01";
    Date parsedDate = parser.parse(dateString);

    String formattedDateString = formatter.format(parsedDate);

    System.out.println("Read String '" + dateString + "' as '" + parsedDate + "', formatted as '" + formattedDateString + "'");
```

When I run this, I get:

`Read String '05/27/2014 23:01' as 'Sun Dec 29 23:01:00 EST 2013', formatted as 'December 29, 2013 23:01`'

Answer (score 0):

Goal

1. Convert String to Date with the format you have it in
2. Output that date as a String in the format you want

Code:

```
String date = "05/27/2014 23:01";
//convert the String to Date based on its existing format
Date df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").parse(date);
System.out.println("date  " +df); 
//now output the Date as a string in the format you want
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(dt1.format(df));
```

Output:

```
date  Tue May 27 23:01:00 CDT 2014
May 27, 2014 23:01
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this >>

```
    String s = sd.format(d);
    String s1 = sd1.format(d);
```

Here Is the full code >>

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class dt {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, YYYY");
    SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");



            String s = sd.format(d);
        String s1 = sd1.format(d);

    System.out.println(s +" "+ s1);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have bothered to do a bit of searching before posting. StackOverflow.com has many questions and answers like this already.

But for the sake of posterity, here's some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library. Avoid the java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java as they are badly designed and implemented. In Java 8, continue to use Joda-Time or switch to the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) defined by [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Those new classes were inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected.

Joda-Time has many features aimed at formatting output. Joda-Time offers built-in standard (ISO 8601) formats. Some classes render strings with format and language appropriate to the host computer's locale, or you can specify a locale. And Joda-Time lets you define your own funky formats as well. Searching for "joda" + "format" will get you many examples.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String input = "05/27/2014" + " " + "23:01";
```

Parse that string…

```java
// Assuming that string is for UTC/GMT, pass the built-in constant "DateTimeZone.UTC".
// If that string was stored as-is for a specific time zone (NOT a good idea), pass an appropriate DateTimeZone instance.
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTime = formatterInput.parseDateTime( input );
```

Ideally you would store the values in an appropriate date-time format in a database. If not possible, then store as a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, set to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT (no time zone offset).

```java
// Usually best to write out date-times in ISO 8601 format in the UTC time zone (no time zone offset, 'Z' = Zulu).
String saveThisStringToStorage = dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString(); // Convert to UTC if not already in UTC.
```

Do your business logic and storage in UTC generally. Switch to local time zones and localized formatting only in the user-interface portion of your app.

```java
// Convert to a localized format (string) only as needed in the user-interface, using the user's time zone.
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime().withLocale( Locale.US ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );
String showUserThisString = formatterOutput.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "saveThisStringToStorage: " + saveThisStringToStorage );
System.out.println( "showUserThisString: " + showUserThisString );
```

When run…

```
input: 05/27/2014 23:01
dateTime: 2014-05-27T23:01:00.000Z
saveThisStringToStorage: 2014-05-27T23:01:00.000Z
showUserThisString: May 27, 2014 7:01:00 PM
```