# SimpleDateFormat wrong result Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

My input in this case is `2012-09-28` but I receive
`01/01/2011` 
I would like to receive `09/28/2012`

```
main(){
 val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val originalFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val targetFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY")
    val date = originalFormat.parse(scan.next())
    val formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date)
    println(formattedDate)
}
```

What is my code missing?

Comment: Your code is missing a modern library for dates and times, but leaving that aside, your patterns look suspicous: only upper-case letters... Those patterns are case sensitive, `y` for example is different from `Y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add colon to 24 hour time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862558/add-colon-to-24-hour-time-in-java) (I know the title doesn’t sound related, but I nevertheless believe the core of the question is the same.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modern API for parsing and formatting date and time is `java.time`, which was introduced with Java 8. You can either import the [ThreeTenAbp](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) or use [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to make it work in Android API versions below 26.

The following example uses `java.time` and considers the input of the two different formats you posted (one in your question and one as a comment to the first answer).

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    // create a formatter that parses the two different EXPECTED input formats
    val inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[uu-MM-dd][uuuu-MM-dd]");
    // parse the input
    val localDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(scan.next(), inputFormatter)
    // define a formatter with the desired output format
    val targetFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu")
    // then create a String with the desired output format
    val formattedDate: String = localDate.format(targetFormat)
    // and print it
    println(formattedDate)
}
```

The result for the inputs `12-09-30` or `2012-09-30` is **`09/30/2012`** in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Colud you try this way?

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val originalFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val targetFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
    val date = originalFormat.parse(scan.next())
    val formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date)
    println(formattedDate)
}
```

`d` is a day in the month. (ex_10)
`D` is a day in the year. (ex_189)

`y` is the year. (ex_1996; 96)
`Y` is week year. (ex_2009; 09)

Comment: Yes I tried and it works as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` and `dd` instead of `DD`.

`DD` is the day of year while `dd` is the day of month.

`YYYY` is the week year and `yyyy` is the regular year.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat?hl=en

Comment: 12-09-30 -> 09/30/0012 why?

Comment: 12 interpreted as 4-digit year `yyyy` is 0012.